# Remove white background from image to blend with parent background

Tags: java, android, image, png

See below screenshot:

[image]

How can I take away the white background around the green arrows?  Just in case it matters, the arrows have `onClickListeners` attached to them.

```
ImageView left, right;
left.setImageResource(R.drawable.left_arrow);
right.setImageResource(R.drawable.right_arrow);
```

Comment: You should edit the image on your computer and save it without background

Comment: How?  I've trimmed as much white as I can off the picture so it is just a square.  Please note all I have to edit with is Paint.

Comment: Paint will not remove white pixels. You can erase white color with Photoshop easily or search for some online tool.

Comment: I use GIMP for this, it can be downloaded for free, and you should search for an option called "Color to Alpha"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually those white spaces have nothing to do with coding or layout style. That is the original image which causes the white spaces.
You have to edit your image (using some editing tools like Photoshop or gimp) to replace those white pixels to transparent.